# how to write query only displaying year in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to write a query like this:

[image]

Comment: `extract(year from datecol)`

Comment: be more specific please..
you already have a table and do you want to select the data from that?
or do you need to create a table which stores date as only year

Answer (score 1):

Below is the three different example to extract Date from a Date & Time filed or from a given date value.

```
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') from dual;

select extract(year from sysdate) from dual;

select extract(year from to_date('15-JAN-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY')) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second post, either you have to create the table like below, to accept the number value directly.

```
create table olympic_sprts (OLYMPIC_YEAR number(4), SPORT varchar2(25), GENDER varchar2(10), EVENT varchar2(40), MEDAL varchar2(10), NOC varchar2(10), ATHLETE varchar2(25));
```

Or, you can use the below example to insert year in number, but database automatically takes its day and month as, "01-May" because currently we running in month of May.

```
insert into olympic_sprts (OLYMPIC_YEAR, SPORT, GENDER, EVENT, MEDAL, NOC, ATHLETE) values (to_date('2016','YYYY'), 'Archery', 'M','Mens Individual','Gold',' KOR', 'KU Bonchan');
```

I will suggest to use first example, change the datatype of column "OLYMPIC_YEAR" from timestamp to "NUMBER(4)" that will be better to manage in future even.

Answer (score 0):

```
 create table olympic_sprts (OLYMPIC_YEAR char(4), SPORT varchar2(25),
 GENDER varchar2(10), EVENT varchar2(40), MEDAL varchar2(10), NOC
 varchar2(10), ATHLETE varchar2(25));

 insert into olympic_sprts (OLYMPIC_YEAR, SPORT, GENDER, EVENT, MEDAL,
 NOC, ATHLETE) values ('2016','Archery', 'M','Mens Individual','Gold','
 KOR', 'KU Bonchan');

 select to_char(OLYMPIC_YEAR,'YYYY'),SPORT, GENDER, EVENT, MEDAL, NOC,
 ATHLETE from olympic_sprts;
```